# VBA Code if Value of Cell change by a specified amount

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find a vba code that is activated if the value in a particular cell changes by a specific amount. The code is supposed to work, regardless of whether the value has been changed manually or by a formula.

The trigger is supposed to be if the cell value changes from positive to negative or from negative to positive and the outcome should be the recording of today's date ("=TODAY()").

I found a lot of solutions with target.value of the cell but none with actual changes in value. Anyone?

Comment: You will need to store the old value someplace -- either on a hidden worksheet, or in a global variable that is initialized perhaps when you open the workbook, or worksheet -- and compare that with target value using a worksheet change or worksheet caclulate event. Modify the code you have found to do so, and post back with any problems.

Comment: `target.value` is actually the answer. Just look into the `Worksheet_Change` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx It gets triggered each time the value of a cell changes (regardless of the reason, unless the value has been changed without opening the file).

Comment: Thx Ron, but is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no alternative to Ron's proposal. You could go for the option to (1) `Undo`, (2) look at the value before change, and then (3) `redo`. But that is pretty insecure and can lead to incorrect results at times. If you have an SQL Server available then you could look into using this with an underlying trigger. There you will have the `inserted`, `updated`, and `deleted` tables available to compare values. But within pure Excel your options are limited.

Comment: @Ralph Are you sure if a volatile function changes that Worksheet_Change event fires?

Comment: Obviously, that's not going to work either (same as the other exception I mentioned above). I guess we all know that what ever User1111 chooses to implement is not going to be a trustworthy / reliable solution unless he/she is willing to use something that is built for such tasks and can actually handle them adequately. For example a DB server (as suggested before).